Cumulative sum with group by
I have a table with financial transactions, and want to create a running total per day. Is this the correct way to do it? Is there a better way? It seems to work, but I could not find this specific combination (SUM ... OVER with GROUP BY) on stackoverflow, and the nested SUM asks for an extra pair of eyes:
  SELECT date,
    SUM(SUM(amount)) over (PARTITION BY TRUE ORDER BY date) AS value
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date ASC

Example data:
date                      amount

2024-11-01 00:00:00+00    -  1.9
2024-11-01 00:00:00+00    -  1.9
2024-11-02 00:00:00+00    -  1.9
2024-11-02 00:00:00+00      10
2024-11-05 00:00:00+00       3.9
2024-11-08 00:00:00+00    -  1.95
2024-11-13 00:00:00+00    - 10
2024-11-16 00:00:00+00      80
2024-11-18 00:00:00+00      85
2024-11-23 00:00:00+00     498.25
2024-11-27 00:00:00+00    -498.25
2024-11-30 00:00:00+00    -650

Expected result:
date                      amount

2024-11-01 00:00:00+00    -  3.8
2024-11-02 00:00:00+00       4.3
2024-11-05 00:00:00+00       8.2
2024-11-08 00:00:00+00       6.25
2024-11-13 00:00:00+00    -  3.75
2024-11-16 00:00:00+00      76.25
2024-11-18 00:00:00+00     161.25
2024-11-23 00:00:00+00     659.5
2024-11-27 00:00:00+00     161.25
2024-11-30 00:00:00+00    -488.75


Is this the correct way to do it? Do you get the correct result?

A [mcve] is always a great idea when asking for SQL assistance.

What happens if you remove PARTITION BY TRUE?

@jarlh With the current dataset: yes. But I need it to keep working when data is added or removed.

@jarlh Still works when I remove the partitioning. I did not realize that that was possible ^^

A timestamp type column named date is very misleading. If there's a second somewhere, your group by will stop working.

Yeah, I agree. It is initialized via Sequelize as a DataTypes.Date, which made it into a timestamp with time zone.

Well, I think it's difficult to answer what is "correct" or "better" in this case. Obviously, your query is correct and produces the expected result. Except for the point that you will likely better cast the timestamp to a whole date to summarize data of entire days if the time differs.
A simpler way to get the intended result would be DISTINCT ON:
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (trans_date::DATE)
  trans_date::DATE AS trans_date,
  SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY trans_date)
FROM transactions;

But this seems to be slower than your current idea:
SELECT 
  trans_date::DATE,
  SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER (ORDER BY trans_date::DATE) AS value
FROM transactions
GROUP BY trans_date::DATE
ORDER BY trans_date::DATE;

I tried both queries on this db<>fiddle with some random rows. According to the query plan, the DISTINCT ON requires more time.
So in my opinion, your query is fine as it is.

The DISTINCT ON version isn't actually correct in the generalized sense (it only gives you one row per ON value and ignores the other rows), it's only accidentally correct because you are using OVER with the default RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING which means you are cumulatively summing but giving the same result for the same ordering value. If you'd used ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING (generally more efficient), or you'd had dates with a time component, then the results would have been incorrect.

@Charlieface That's a good hint, thank you. Do you agree with my opinion that OP's query is fine for their requirement or would you prefer another way?

Yes it's what I would do, although (at least on SQL Server) it's slightly faster to add ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING to the OVER, the results are the same if you have the GROUP BY.
